# Different scan results with and without carriage return when sending byte stream

Tags: python, sockets

I've got this port scanner written in Python:

```
import argparse
import sys
import socket
import threading


lock = threading.Lock()


def portScanner(host, port):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect((host, port))
        sock.send(b'hakuna matata\r\n')  # <--
        response = sock.recv(1024)
        lock.acquire()
        print(f'[+] {host} on port {port} is open.')
        print(f'Response: {response.decode()}')
    except:
        lock.acquire()
        print(f'[-] {host} on port {port} is closed.')

    finally:
        lock.release()
        sock.close()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-H', dest='host', type=str,
                        help='that\'s the host ip')
    parser.add_argument('-p', dest='port', type=str, help='ports to check')
    options = parser.parse_args()

    if not options.host or not options.port:
        print('Invalid inputs. Exiting ...')
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        host = options.host
        try:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
        except:
            print(f'Couldn\'t resolve {host}.')
            sys.exit(1)
        ports = options.port.split(', ')
        # print(ports)
        for port in ports:
            t = threading.Thread(target=portScanner, args=(host, int(port)))
            t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the script supplying ports 80 and 22 I get both ports are open but when I remove '\r\n' from `send(b'hakuna matata')` I get port 80 is closed. This is super weird. Why is that ? Why do I get two different results just because I add carriage return and new line character into the bytes message ?

Comment: Start by not throwing away your exception information!

Comment: `except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))`  revealed "timed out"

Comment: Why do you send anything at all? Think about that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is a human-readable protocol based on text lines.  The server with which you’re testing evidently waits on the CRLF before **parsing** the line and discovering that it’s nonsense.  You then timeout since it doesn’t immediately send back the 401 it would eventually produce.  Not that this means the port is *closed*; if the `connect` succeeds, the port must be open.

Comment: First contributor who actually **explained** what's happening. Thank you !